# Error bars from lists

Tags: plotting

I have a list of data values, and I'd like to plot error bars showing the maxima and minima that each entry in my data list can take. The data and the maxima and minima are produced outside of *Mathematica* and stored as lists.

How can I plot the data as points, with the max/min values for each point shown as error bars?

From reading other Stack Exchange posts, I know that the *Mathematica* documentation for things like error bars and `ErrorListPlot` is woefully lacking. What would be the easiest way of plotting them as I need?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Do you have any data that can be used by answerers as a demonstration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you have your data in the following format: `{xcoord, ycoord, error}`. You can then transform it into a format usable with `ErrorListPlot` from the `` ErrorBars` `` built-in package.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
```

Let's generate some noisy data and errors:

```
data = Table[{x, 2 x + 3 + RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}], RandomReal[{0.3, 0.5}]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.2}]
```

> {{-2., -0.631418, 0.401375}, {-1.8, -0.324501, 
>     0.478881}, {-1.6, -0.38702, 0.417729}, {-1.4, 0.465309, 
>     0.469964}, {-1.2, 0.349653, 0.400248}, {-1., 1.29763, 
>     0.411828}, {-0.8, 0.98644, 0.30355}, {-0.6, 1.99419, 
>     0.350669}, {-0.4, 1.83254, 0.305295}, {-0.2, 2.5138, 0.354081}, {0.,
>      3.31652, 0.391467}, {0.2, 3.5273, 0.45806}, {0.4, 3.56931, 
>     0.30968}, {0.6, 4.48919, 0.356931}, {0.8, 4.33623, 0.426343}, {1., 
>     5.3088, 0.386963}, {1.2, 4.94164, 0.356271}, {1.4, 5.30908, 
>     0.449249}, {1.6, 6.29378, 0.464905}, {1.8, 6.23364, 0.308909}, {2., 
>     7.00361, 0.328092}}

`ErrorListPlot` wants data formatted as `{{xcoord, ycoord}, ErrorBar[value]}`. We can transform the data we have to fit that format:

```
formattedData = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} & @@@ data

{ {{-2., -0.631418}, ErrorBar[0.401375]}, 
  {{-1.8, -0.324501}, ErrorBar[0.478881]}, <<...>>} }
```

Then we use `ErrorListPlot` on the transformed data set:

```
ErrorListPlot[formattedData]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

As of V12, [`ErrorListPlot` functionality has been folded into `ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html).

Using the same data as in [MarcoB's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108037/29734),

```
data = {{-2., -0.631418, 0.401375}, {-1.8, -0.324501, 0.478881}, {-1.6, -0.38702, 0.417729},
        {-1.4, 0.465309, 0.469964}, {-1.2, 0.349653, 0.400248}, {-1., 1.29763, 0.411828},
        {-0.8, 0.98644, 0.30355}, {-0.6, 1.99419, 0.350669}, {-0.4, 1.83254, 0.305295},
        {-0.2, 2.5138, 0.354081}, {0., 3.31652, 0.391467}, {0.2, 3.5273, 0.45806},
        {0.4, 3.56931, 0.30968}, {0.6, 4.48919, 0.356931}, {0.8, 4.33623, 0.426343},
        {1., 5.3088, 0.386963}, {1.2, 4.94164, 0.356271}, {1.4, 5.30908, 0.449249},
        {1.6, 6.29378, 0.464905}, {1.8, 6.23364, 0.308909}, {2., 7.00361, 0.328092}};
```

we can use `Around` to make the error bars:

```
ListPlot[{#1, Around[#2, #3]}& @@@ data]
```

This makes the same plot as in the other answer.  The error bars can be formatted using the option `IntervalMarkersStyle`.