# best fitting crossing divides region plots with different background colors

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fitting

We have two lists:

```
l1= {{0.1, -0.393375}, {0.2, -0.19808}, {0.3, -0.107879}, {0.4, -0.065965}, {0.5, -0.0446273}, {0.6, -0.0321304}, {0.7, -0.0237551}, {0.8, -0.0175364}, {0.9, -0.0125716}, {1., -0.00840498}, {1.1, -0.00478801}, {1.2, -0.0015762}, {1.3, 0.00131971}, {1.4, 0.00395822}, {1.5, 0.00637993},
{1.6, 0.00861463}, {1.7, 0.0106852}, {1.8, 0.01261}, {1.9,  0.0144042}, {2., 0.0160805}}
l2= {{0.1, -0.409484}, {0.2, -0.240017}, {0.3, -0.155611}, {0.4, -0.109464}, {0.5, -0.0809348}, {0.6, -0.061749}, {0.7, -0.0479979}, {0.8, -0.037611}, {0.9, -0.0294156}, {1., -0.0227167}, {1.1, -0.0170864}, {1.2, -0.0122509}, {1.3, -0.0080281}, {1.4, -0.00429215}, {1.5, -0.000952946},
{1.6, 0.00205623}, {1.7,  0.00478628}, {1.8, 0.00727704}, {1.9, 0.00956036}, {2., 0.0116622}}
error = {0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005};
```

By `withErrorl1 = Transpose[{l1[[All, 1]], l1[[All, 2]],error}]` and similar for l2 we put error bar to data.

By
`ErrorListPlot[{withErrorl1, withErrorl2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]`
we have plot as below

[image]

**Problem**

the desired case is a plot in which we firstly execute the best fitting of data separately and by determining the crossing of best fitting to the horizontal axis, divide the plot region by vertical lines and limited region have background colors as: (however, coloring by paint has covered numeric labels)

[image]

Comment: Interpolate or fit data, find roots, add `Rectangles` to `Epilog` or play with `Filling`. Where are you stuck? p.s. `a = 0;b = 1;Plot[
 {If[x < a, 1], If[a < x < b, 1], If[b < x, 1]}, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> Bottom,
 PlotRange -> 2 ]`

Comment: I have never had any experience about fitting. I saw the help of mathematica but I confused, I am trying to understand what happen for fitting. actually I don't know does errorbars effect on fitting or not?!!

Comment: @Kuba, How can I guess the initial function to fit my data?!!!!

Comment: Usually it's based on a mathematical model/guess which describes phonomenon tested in an experiment the data is gathered from. But this site it not a place to teach people what fitting or a scientific method is. We can help you using `NonlinearModelFit` and friends if you are stuck.

Comment: Meanwhile you can take a look at `Interpolation`.

Comment: Ok, I am checking, Kuba, your help and guidance is always very fruitful. I thank you again and if you let me I delete this post?

Comment: I don't know, maybe you can figure it out and answer. p.s. if you don't know/care about the model you can try with `FindFormula`, add parameters and put them in `NonlinearModelFit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should work with the available options. And see [How to | Fit Models with Measurement Errors](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/FitModelsWithMeasurementErrors.html).

Set up and have some Data (see [Error bars from lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108036/error-bars-from-lists/108037#108037) @MarcoB):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
data = Table[{x, 2 x + 3 + RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}], 
RandomReal[{0.3, 0.5}]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.2}];
data2 = Table[{x, 2 x + 5 + RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}], 
RandomReal[{0.3, 0.5}]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.2}];

formattedData = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} & @@@ data;
formattedData2 = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} & @@@ data2;

elp1 = ErrorListPlot[{formattedData2, formattedData}, Joined -> True, 
PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Yellow}}]
```

[image]

```
Options[elp1]
```

[image]

```
pr = Options[elp1][[4]]
```

> PlotRange->{{-2.,2.},{-0.701473,8.67711}}

```
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = pr[[2]]
```

> {{-2.,2.},{-0.701473,8.67711}}

```
Show[elp1, 
Graphics[{Opacity[0.3], Red, Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {0, ymax}], 
Blue, Rectangle[{0, ymin}, {1, ymax}], Green, 
Rectangle[{1, ymin}, {2, ymax}]}]]
```

[image]

The Intersections with x, you can find like so:

```
il1 = Interpolation[l1];
il2 = Interpolation[l2];
ip1 = Plot[il1[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red];
ip2 = Plot[il2[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
lp1 = ListPlot[{l1, l2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}];
Show[lp1, ip1, ip2]
```

[image]

```
Solve[il1[x] == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> 1.2532}}

```
Solve[il2[x] == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> 1.53058}}

You can assign the results to Variables and use them in your calculations:

```
x1 = x /. sol1
```

> {1.2532}

```
x2 = x /. sol2
```

> {1.53058}

Comment: Most of your answer fundamentally clarify the solutions of problem. They are wonderful and enjoyable.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you want and here is the code:

```
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} =MinMax /@ Transpose[l1~Join~l2];
f1 = Interpolation@l1;
f2 = Interpolation@l2;
{crmin, crmax} = x /. FindRoot[#[x] == 0, {x, 1}] & /@ {f1, f2};

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
Show[ErrorListPlot[{withErrorl1, withErrorl2}, 
Prolog -> {Opacity@.3, Red, Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {crmin, ymax}],Blue, Rectangle[{crmin, ymin}, {crmax, ymax}], Darker@Green,Rectangle[{crmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]}, 
GridLines -> {{crmin, crmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, PlotRange -> Full,ImageSize -> Large], 
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> Full]]
```

[image: result]

---

## Explanation

Since what you need is, seemingly, fill everywhere, so `Filling` option will not help. So here I used `Prolog` to fulfill your goal. Also, I think you may need some reference grid lines, so I added `GridLines` to do this.

The cross finding is done by implementing `Interpolation` and `FindRoot`.

Also, as @Kuba have said, in case the OP only want to get a line (or function) connecting all the points, Interpolation can be a good choice, but if OP would like to have a fit function, Try FindFit. :)

Comment: Actually I did not quite get your point, sorry. Maybe you can edit it. Thanks !

Comment: the point is that `Interpolation` isn't performing a best fit procedure and respecting errors.

Comment: @Wjx, I am definitely using Interpolation@l1; but I see an error as  "The point 1.1` in dimension 1 is duplicated."

Comment: I found it. an elements was repeated. So sorry.

Comment: @Kuba yes, but I suppose that op simply want to add a line connecting those points to make the plot looks better~ Certainly Interpolation shall be replaced by FindFit or so if we want to get a explicit fit function.

Comment: @Wjx I'm fine with Interpolation if that fits OP needs, but future readers can be confused so it is good to say more than not :)

Comment: @Kuba I suppose I'll add an explanation. :)

Comment: @Wjx this or reduce OP's question, I'm not longer sure what is this about :) stopped tracking the discussion