# Displays the mean and standard deviation on the same line

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I have data displayed on a line,

I want to present the mean as a horizontal line and a standard deviation as a vertical line.

Example  to code:  `Show[ListLinePlot[Mean[analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[1 ;;18]]],PlotStyle->Dashed,PlotRange->{{0,8},{0,10}},  AxesLabel-> {"Repeat","Average velocity(cm/sec)"},PlotLabel-> "Hives with 1: 1 diet"], ListLinePlot[Mean[analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[1 ;;6]]], PlotStyle -> Blue], ListLinePlot[Mean[analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[7 ;;12]]], PlotStyle -> Green], ListLinePlot[StandardDeviation[analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[7 ;;12]]], PlotStyle -> Green], ListLinePlot[Mean[analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[13 ;;18]]], PlotStyle -> Red]]`

The result

[image]

How do I make the bottom green line (standard deviation) appear vertically on the top green line (mean)?

Comment: Is this (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108036/error-bars-from-lists) what you want?

Comment: For version 12.0 or later, use [`Around`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
analysBeeSumOfVelocity = RandomReal[{3,5},{18,8}];
ListLinePlot[
    MapAt[
        Around
        , {
        analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[1 ;;18]],
        analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[1 ;;6]],
        analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[7 ;;12]],
        analysBeeSumOfVelocity[[13 ;;18]]
        }
       , {All, All}
    ]
, PlotStyle-> {Directive[Gray,Dashed], Blue, Green , Red}
, PlotRange-> {{0,8},{0,10}}
, FrameLabel-> {"Repeat","Average velocity [cm/sec]"}
, PlotLabel-> "Hives with 1: 1 diet"
, PlotTheme-> "Scientific"
]
```

[image]

Comment: use Around fix the problem, Thanks.

Comment: @erez next time please provide the data so we don't have to speculate and create our own.